# How to get value of checkbox on check or uncheck without submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I want to change value when someone check or uncheck checkbox. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    if($params['status'] == "2"){ 
?>
        <div class="pull-right" id="confirm-ship">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chkone"><br>
            if(checkbox == check){
                <span>Confirmed</span>
            }else{
                <span>Not Confirmed</span>
            }
        </div>
<?php
     }
?>
```

I want to show message confirmed or not confirmed when someone click on checkbox without submit a page or reload a page. Is it possible, anyone help me?

I just added below code on above scenario just for giving an idea.

```
if(checkbox == check){
    <span>Confirmed</span>
}else{
    <span>Not Confirmed</span>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to set an event listener to listen for the change event and trigger a function.

If you give your elements `id`'s you can make things easier to target that element.

You will also want to place your javascript into `<script>` tags. Some people place them in the body of the page or at the very bottom. Me personally, I like to place my in the `<head>` tag as using `window.onload` will only attempt to `getElementById()` when the page has loaded.

```js
window.onload=function(){ // Trigger when the page is ready
  //Set change event 
  document.getElementById('Confirmation').addEventListener('change', Confirm, false);
}

function Confirm(){
  var Confirmation=document.getElementById('Confirmation').checked;
  var Message;
  if(Confirmation){
    Message="Confirmed";
  }else{
    Message="Not Confirmed"
  }
  document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML=Message;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Confirmation" />
<span id="Result">Not Confirmed</span>
```

If you have any questions about the above source code please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: @MuhammadAwais You are very welcome. If you have any questions feel free to ask and I will display more detail/explanation if needed.

Comment: Sounds good. For now, it's perfectly working. Sure, net i will let you know if  any query about JS. Thank you so much for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

The **.checked** property of a checkbox DOM element will tell give you the checked state of the element.

```
   <input id="chktype" type="checkbox" class="chkone"><br>

  if(document.getElementById('chktype').checked) {
       alert('Checked');
    } else {
        alert('Not Checked');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
$('.yourcheckbox').click(function() {
    if( $('.yourcheckbox').is(":checked") ) {
       do stuff
    } else {
       do other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using jQuery. Include the jQuery file in your head section:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <?php 

     if($params['status'] == "2"){ ?>
      <div  class="pull-right" id="confirm-ship">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkone"><br>
      <span></span>
      </div>
    <?php  }
      ?>
      <script>
          $('.chkone').change(function(){

      if($(this).prop('checked')==true)
      {
        $('span').html('Confirmed');  
      }
      else
      {
          $('span').html('Not Confirmed');
      }
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: its simple you can try this

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code :

```
<div class="pull-right" id="confirm-ship">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkone" id="chkone"><br>
```

Use javascript :

```
$('.chkone').click(function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            //if checked do something
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
```